# Iterate COUNTIF on a column by pasting form over the column

Tags: copy-paste, libreoffice, countif

I would like to iterate the countif form to an entire column with LibreOffice

The form is:

=COUNTIF(P$2:P$5041,R2)

The Table looks like this:

```
P                               R
Exp_NotGen_Aha_NotSolved_Recog  Exp_Gen_Aha_Solved_Novel
Exp_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Rem        Exp_Gen_Aha_Solved_Rem  
Base_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Novel     Exp_Gen_Aha_Solved_Recog    
Exp_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Recog      Exp_Gen_Aha_NotSolved_Novel 
Exp_Gen_NoAha_NotSolved_Novel   Exp_Gen_Aha_NotSolved_Rem
Base_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Recog     Exp_Gen_Aha_NotSolved_Recog 
Exp_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Rem        Exp_Gen_NoAha_Solved_Novel
(...)
```

So with my form I intent to count up every time I find a name on the column P, which is the same as the name on the column R.

The form returns me the correct number of occurrences (which is e.g 41 on the first line of the column R). But then, when I try to copy and paste the form in order to repeat the calculation for the other rows in R, then I get just blank cells. If i sellect the cell I can see that the form is there (e.g this is what I get when I click over the cell with the result of R2: =COUNTIF(P$2:P$5041,R3) ). But there's no visible output.

Does anybody has any idea why do I get no output?

Answer (score 0):

I know what was the problem. The forms in the sheet weren't being updated. To solve this problem you have to do the following:

Choose Data - Calculate - AutoCalculate (you see a check mark next to the command when AutoCalculate is enabled).

That's it.